# Recharts.js passing trying to pass API data

Tags: next.js13, recharts

the following cose, d3Data is a promise being returned which I can map to a table or another component.
I am facing issue when tryind to pass this data to a charts library like recharts or d3.js.

```
import { getProjectList } from "@/lib/D3Helper";
import { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend } from "recharts";

const TestChart = async () => {
  const d3Data = await getProjectList().then();

    // console.log(lineData.status)


  //console.log(d3Data)
  return <div>TestChart
  { <LineChart data={d3Data}>
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Price" stroke="#000" />
      <XAxis dataKey="Name" />
      <YAxis />
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
    </LineChart> }
  
  </div>;
};

export default TestChart;
```

The above code, for example is giving the following error:

```
Server Error
Error: Super expression must either be null or a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
_inherits
node_modules\recharts\lib\component\DefaultLegendContent.js (22:112)
_inherits
node_modules\recharts\lib\component\DefaultLegendContent.js (36:2)
_react
node_modules\recharts\lib\component\DefaultLegendContent.js (179:2)
(rsc)/./node_modules/recharts/lib/component/DefaultLegendContent.js
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/.next/server/vendor-chunks/recharts.js (320:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:42)
require
node_modules\recharts\lib\component\Legend.js (11:28)
(rsc)/./node_modules/recharts/lib/component/Legend.js
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/.next/server/vendor-chunks/recharts.js (360:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:42)
require
node_modules\recharts\lib\index.js (326:14)
(rsc)/./node_modules/recharts/lib/index.js
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/.next/server/vendor-chunks/recharts.js (420:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:42)
eval
webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/components/visualizations/TestChart.js (8:145)
(rsc)/./src/components/visualizations/TestChart.js
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/.next/server/app/page.js (525:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:42)
eval
webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/page.js (7:94)
(rsc)/./src/app/page.js
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/.next/server/app/page.js (514:1)
Function.__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:42)
runNextTicks
node:internal/process/task_queues (60:5)
listOnTimeout
node:internal/timers (540:9)
process.processTimers
node:internal/timers (514:7)
async e_
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (11:405134)
async eJ
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (11:409224)
async eG
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (11:409699)
async eG
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (11:409830)
async eX
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (11:413242)
async
file:///C:/Users/****/GitHub/****/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (11:413716)
```

I tried using await keyword but cannot use it for somthing that is just data and not function.

Comment: Can you try by adding () after return and wrap it.
and also remove {} from <Linehcart>

Comment: Hi @Mohindersingh, Yes that helped.
Thanks.
Now a new issue. I am pulling promise API data into this component, and the PureComponent in Recharts is asking for it to use client. But the component function i am using is async. Any idea how I can fix that ?

Comment: Hi Sandeep, I guess Recharts do something on client side thats why it is asking for use client. Please verify that what you are doing with Recharts does not require any client side things, for example scree width, viewport, observer or window object. It could be anything which is only available in browser. If this library use anything like that, then you need to use 'use client'.